# SQL Query Returning Duplicate values after using UNION and Distinct

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL query where I am trying to get distinct values after making union of two queries. I have already used Distinct in both of the queries.

I have `RegID` as primary key in the `Registration` table and for each entry in registration table there are corresponding entries in `RoomType` i.e, `RoomType` table has `RegID` as foreign key.

Now the problem is if have more than one entry in `RoomType` table for a particular `RegID` I am getting duplicate Regid's.

My query print is like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    dbo.tbRegistration.RegID, 
    dbo.tbRegistration.PropertyName, dbo.tbRegistration.IsActive, 
    dbo.tbRegistration.Stars, dbo.tbRegistration.City, 
    dbo.tbRegistration.Address, 
    dbo.tbHotelImages.MainImage, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img1, 
    dbo.tbHotelImages.Img2, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img3, 
    dbo.tbHotelImages.Img4, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img5, 
    dbo.tbHotelImages.Img6, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img7, 
    dbo.tbHotelImages.Img8, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img9, 
    dbo.tbRegistration.PropertyID, 
    dbo.tbHotelFeatures.*, 
    dbo.tbBillingPlan.BaseRate, dbo.tbRoomType.Name as RoomTypeName
FROM         
    dbo.tbRoomType 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.tbRegistration ON dbo.tbRoomType.RegID = dbo.tbRegistration.RegID  
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.tbBillingPlan ON dbo.tbRoomType.RTID = dbo.tbBillingPlan.RTID    
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.tbHotelFeatures ON dbo.tbRegistration.RegID = dbo.tbHotelFeatures.RegID  
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.tbHotelImages ON dbo.tbRegistration.RegID = dbo.tbHotelImages.RegID                                          
WHERE 
    tbRegistration.PMS = 0 
    AND tbRegistration.Stars IN (0) OR 1=1 
    AND (tbRegistration.City LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%')  
    AND (tbRoomType.Adults >= @Adults OR tbRoomType.Children >= @Children)
    AND (dbo.GetFreeRoomType(dbo.tbRoomType.RTID, @CheckIn, @CheckOut) > 0) 
    AND dbo.tbRegistration.IsActive = 1     

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT 
    dbo.tbRegistration.RegID  , dbo.tbRegistration.PropertyName, dbo.tbRegistration.IsActive, dbo.tbRegistration.Stars, dbo.tbRegistration.City, dbo.tbRegistration.Address, 
                      dbo.tbHotelImages.MainImage, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img1, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img2, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img3, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img4, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img5, 
                      dbo.tbHotelImages.Img6, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img7, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img8, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img9, dbo.tbRegistration.PropertyID    , 
                      dbo.tbHotelFeatures.*, dbo.tbBillingPlan.BaseRate,dbo.tbRoomType.Name as RoomTypeName
FROM         dbo.tbRoomType left OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbRegistration ON dbo.tbRoomType.RegID = dbo.tbRegistration.RegID  left OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbBillingPlan ON dbo.tbRoomType.RTID = dbo.tbBillingPlan.RTID    LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbHotelFeatures ON dbo.tbRegistration.RegID = dbo.tbHotelFeatures.RegID  LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbHotelImages ON dbo.tbRegistration.RegID = dbo.tbHotelImages.RegID                                           
       Where tbRegistration.PMS=1  and   tbRegistration.Stars IN (   0 ) or 1=1 and    (tbRegistration.City like  '%' + @SearchText + '%' )    

and (tbRoomType.Adults>=@Adults  or tbRoomType.Children>=@Children )
 and(dbTestSparrowPMS . dbo.GetFreeRoomType(dbo.tbRoomType.ID, @CheckIn, @CheckOut) >0) and dbo.tbRegistration.IsActive=1



   order by  tbRegistration.RegID
```

and My Procedure is like this:

```
USE [dbTestSearchMyHotel]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[prRegistrationSearchFreeHotels]    Script Date: 04/01/2013 12:06:26 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[prRegistrationSearchFreeHotels]   -- 's','4/27/2013','4/28/2013',1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here select * from tbRegistration where Stars in(1,4)

@SearchText varchar(4000),
@CheckIn date,
@CheckOut date,
@Adults int,
@Children int,
@Min float,
@Max float,
@OneStar bit,
@TwoStar bit,
@ThreeStar bit,
@FourStar bit,
@FiveStar bit

    AS
     Declare @SQLQuery AS NVarchar(4000)
Declare @ParamDefinition AS NVarchar(4000) 
declare @n as bit
set @n=0
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

  Set @SQLQuery='SELECT DISTINCT 
                      dbo.tbRegistration.RegID  , dbo.tbRegistration.PropertyName,dbo.tbRegistration.IsActive, dbo.tbRegistration.Stars, dbo.tbRegistration.City, dbo.tbRegistration.Address, 
                      dbo.tbHotelImages.MainImage, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img1, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img2, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img3, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img4, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img5, 
                      dbo.tbHotelImages.Img6, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img7, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img8, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img9, dbo.tbRegistration.PropertyID    , 
                      dbo.tbHotelFeatures.*, dbo.tbBillingPlan.BaseRate,dbo.tbRoomType.Name as RoomTypeName
FROM         dbo.tbRoomType left OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbRegistration ON dbo.tbRoomType.RegID = dbo.tbRegistration.RegID  left OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbBillingPlan ON dbo.tbRoomType.RTID = dbo.tbBillingPlan.RTID    LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbHotelFeatures ON dbo.tbRegistration.RegID = dbo.tbHotelFeatures.RegID  LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbHotelImages ON dbo.tbRegistration.RegID = dbo.tbHotelImages.RegID                                          
                              Where  tbRegistration.PMS=0 and  tbRegistration.Stars IN (   ' 
     if @OneStar =1 
     begin
    set @n =1
    set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +'  1  '
    end

  if @TwoStar =1 
  begin
     if @n =1
     begin
     set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +' , 2 '
       end
     else
     begin
     set @n=1
     set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +' 2 '
      end
 end

  if @ThreeStar =1 
  begin
     if @n =1
     begin
    set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +' , 3 '
    end
    else
     begin
     set @n=1
     set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +' 3  '
    end
 end

  if @FourStar =1 
  begin
     if @n =1
     begin
    set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +' , 4 '
    end
    else
    begin
     set @n=1
      set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +' 4 '
    end
    end

  if @FiveStar =1 
  begin
    if @n =1
     begin
     set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +' , 5 '
    end
     else
     begin
     set @n=1
     set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +' 5 '
    end
    end                         
   if @n=0
 begin
  set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +' 0 ) or 1=1 and '
 end      
 else
 begin                      
 set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +' )    and ' 
 end
 set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +'    (tbRegistration.City like  ''%'' + @SearchText + ''%'' )  

 and (tbRoomType.Adults>=@Adults  or tbRoomType.Children>=@Children )
 and( dbo.GetFreeRoomType(dbo.tbRoomType.RTID, @CheckIn, @CheckOut) >0) and dbo.tbRegistration.IsActive=1    '  
 if @Min > 0 and @Max > 0   
 set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +' and (tbBillingPlan.BaseRate>=@Min) and  (tbBillingPlan.BaseRate<=@Max)  '





  set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +' union  '
  set @n=0
Set @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery+'SELECT DISTINCT 
                      dbo.tbRegistration.RegID  , dbo.tbRegistration.PropertyName, dbo.tbRegistration.IsActive, dbo.tbRegistration.Stars, dbo.tbRegistration.City, dbo.tbRegistration.Address, 
                      dbo.tbHotelImages.MainImage, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img1, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img2, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img3, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img4, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img5, 
                      dbo.tbHotelImages.Img6, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img7, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img8, dbo.tbHotelImages.Img9, dbo.tbRegistration.PropertyID    , 
                      dbo.tbHotelFeatures.*, dbo.tbBillingPlan.BaseRate,dbo.tbRoomType.Name as RoomTypeName
FROM         dbo.tbRoomType left OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbRegistration ON dbo.tbRoomType.RegID = dbo.tbRegistration.RegID  left OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbBillingPlan ON dbo.tbRoomType.RTID = dbo.tbBillingPlan.RTID    LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbHotelFeatures ON dbo.tbRegistration.RegID = dbo.tbHotelFeatures.RegID  LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbHotelImages ON dbo.tbRegistration.RegID = dbo.tbHotelImages.RegID                                           
       Where tbRegistration.PMS=1  and   tbRegistration.Stars IN (  ' 
     if @OneStar =1 
     begin
    set @n =1
 set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +'  1  '
 end
     if @TwoStar =1 
     begin
         if @n =1
        begin
        set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +', 2 '
        end
        else
        begin
         set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +' 2 '
         set @n=1
            end
     end
  if @ThreeStar =1 
  begin
         if @n =1
          begin
        set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +' , 3 '
         end
        else
         begin
         set @n=1
        set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +' 3'
            end
 end

  if @FourStar =1 
  begin
         if @n =1
         begin
        set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +' , 4 '
        end
        else
        begin
        Set @n=1
        set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +' 4 '
        end
 end
   if @FiveStar =1 
   begin
         if @n =1
         begin
        set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +', 5 '
        end
        else
        begin
        Set @n=1
         set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +' 5 '
        end
 end                         
  if @n=0
 begin
  set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +' 0 ) or 1=1 and '
 end      
 else
 begin                      
 set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +' )    and ' 
 end
 set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +'   (tbRegistration.City like  ''%'' + @SearchText + ''%'' )    

and (tbRoomType.Adults>=@Adults  or tbRoomType.Children>=@Children )
 and(dbTestSparrowPMS . dbo.GetFreeRoomType(dbo.tbRoomType.ID, @CheckIn, @CheckOut) >0) and dbo.tbRegistration.IsActive=1



  '  

 if @Min > 0 and @Max > 0   
 set @SQLQuery =@SQLQuery +' and (tbBillingPlan.BaseRate>=@Min) and  (tbBillingPlan.BaseRate<=@Max) '



 set @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery + ' order by  tbRegistration.RegID'
  --

       Set @ParamDefinition = ' 
@SearchText varchar(4000),
@CheckIn date,
@CheckOut date,
@Adults int,
@Children int,
@Min float,
@Max float,
@OneStar bit,
@TwoStar bit,
@ThreeStar bit,
@FourStar bit,
@FiveStar bit'
   --print @SQLQuery           
    /* Execute the Transact-SQL String with all parameter value's 
       Using sp_executesql Command */
    Execute sp_Executesql     @SQLQuery, 
                @ParamDefinition, 

               @SearchText ,
               @CheckIn ,
               @CheckOut ,
               @Adults ,
               @Children ,
               @Min,
               @Max,
               @OneStar ,
               @TwoStar ,
               @ThreeStar ,
               @FourStar ,
               @FiveStar 



    return



  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNION removes duplicate records (UNION = SELECT DISTINCT), while UNION ALL returns duplicate records. Please check [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/11/sql-server-difference-between-union-vs-union-all-optimal-performance-comparison/) link.

Now in your query you're doing SELECT DISTINCT on both the query and using UNION with them. But If your both query returns different value for one of the column then you'll get both of them and UNION won't remove duplicate.

For e.g

ID  Text

1     A

1     B

So you either have to remove that column having different value and hence returning duplicate records to you if possible. OR add condition that filter out records already selected in first query.

Comment: Nil thx , but I have added a condition (where PMS=0 or PMS=1  in query see my procedure or Query Print) but it is returning dupslicate  rows even then.

Comment: Also both queryies are returning same rows only conditions checked in 2 queries are different.

Comment: If at all your condition should make difference, you should not have the same result. I hope you get my point!